# Activities listed, place blank hour spots around those times

Tags: javascript, jquery, schedule

I'm pulling in a list of activities for TODAY via JSON.

I want to search the times of those activities and then show something for every hour of TODAY that doesn't have an activity so it looks like a daily agenda type list.

3:30pm Activity

4:00pm No Activity

4:30pm No Activity

5:00pm Activity

Comment: @axrwkr I'm sorry! I am just seeing your response. Basically, it is put into the page using Handlebars so I had to kind of work around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! =)

The HTML:

```
<ul id="ulToday">
<li class="post-info act"><time class="" hr="14" min="30">2:30pm</time> Activity</li>
<li class="post-info act"><time class="" hr="16" min="30">2:30pm</time> Activity</li>
</ul>
```

The JS:

```
for (var hour=1; hour<25; hour++) {
    hours = hour;
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12;
    $('#ulToday').append('<li class="' + hour + '"><time>' + hours +' '+ ampm + '</time> No activity</li>');
};
$('.act').each(function(){
             var activityTime = $(this).find('time').attr('hr');
             var activityMin = $(this).find('time').attr('min');
             var actClass = "."+activityTime;
             var activity = $(this);
    if (activityMin != 00) {
        $(actClass).after(activity);
    } else {
        $(actClass).replaceWith(activity);
    };  
});
```